# Flutter: Ignore touch events on a Widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to have a blurred image on top of my other widgets, however, I cannot interact with the widgets below it when I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do the "frosted glass" effect in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter)

Comment: Not really @creativecreatorormaybenot , I want to have the previous page seen blurred not sit a random image and the content which a box seen clearly as if hovering over it with a drop shadow.

Comment: Yes I got that. But because Flutter works exclusively with `Widget`'s the answer of that question is applicable to your question as well. Your whole page can simply be wrapped with a `BackdropFilter`.

Comment: I’ve tried that. The black still shows. I don’t know where that black is coming from. well I kinda do, only happens after the navigate to function. Unless there’s another way to fade in a widget, pass data, and then return it as well if any data has changed ?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

### Solution

You can solve your interaction issue (not being able to interact with the `Widget` below your blurred image) by surrounding your `BackdropFilter` with an [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html).

This means that [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) is the **solution** here because it will **ignore** all touch events for the `Widget`'s passed as its child.

```
IgnorePointer(child: BackdropFilter(...),)
```

You can adjust this attribute by changing the `bool` value of `ignoring`:

```
IgnorePointer(ignoring: false, ...)
```

This will **enable** all *touch events* again.

#### Absorbing

Something interesting to look at here, but unrelated to the problem, is the [`AbsorbPointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) `Widget`, which can be used to **reflect** all *touch events* that occur on its child **onto itself**.

Comment: How about when it's visible? Can I interact with it when I can see it? The only time i don't want to be accessed is when it's hidden.

Comment: Then just simply checked if the widget is visible and if so then activate the IngorePointer via IgnorePointer(ignoring: true, ...)

Comment: Does anyone know why these are not working with WebView in flutter?

Comment: No longer works as of Flutter 3

Comment: @DenisBarzanov What in particular is no longer working for you? The `IgnorePointer` and `AbsorbPointer` widgets have not been altered.

Comment: It was something in my specific case. Turns out they made `gestureSettings` required as of Flutter 3, which broke my custom `RenderWidget`. my b

Comment: Is there something like an AbsorbDrag Widget?

Answer (score 75):

You can either use `IgnorePointer` or `AbsorbPointer`.

- **`IgnorePointer`**

  ```dart
  IgnorePointer(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Not clickable Button'),
    ),
  );
  ```
- **`AbsorbPointer`**

  ```dart
  AbsorbPointer(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Not clickable Button'),
    ),
  );
  ```

---

**What's the difference?**

If there is a widget beneath your main widget which is also capable of receiving click events, and you use `IgnorePointer` on the parent widget, the child widget would still receive the click events.

But using `AbsorbPointer` on main widget won't allow the other widget (beneath main widget) to receive their click events.

Example showing the difference.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          width: 250,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () => print("Button 1"),
            child: Text("Button 1"),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 0,
          width: 250,
          child: IgnorePointer( // replace this with AbsorbPointer and button 1 won't receive click
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => print("Button 2"),
              child: Text("Button 2"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this prevent the onclick on Button 2 as well?  When a run the above in a newly created app, I don't see the print Button 2 output.

Comment: then what about `ignorePointer()` widget. How do we do this.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

The other answers are very appealing.

Lets see a practical example of using `IgnorePointer` widget.

This case is pretty common when we started trying to implement something like toggling a selection on a widget to delete or something like for example.

***Example Senario :***
Holding on a WhatsApp message and delete option coming on top. if tap anywhere else while this option active, it will go.

I implemented it like this.

```
appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('MyApp'), 
         actions: [
            if (_selected != null) // <-- Delete button only appear something selected.
               IconButton(
               icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
               onPressed: () { 
                   // Delete Code here
               }
         ]
      ),
body: GestureDetector(
           behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
           onTap: () { 
                 print('Tapped');
                 setState(() { _selected = null });
           },
           child: IgnorePointer(
           ignoring: _selected != null ? true : false, // <-- Ignore only when selecting something.
           child: Column(
             children: [
              ...

              // This is a sample message 

              GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {  
                 setState(() { _selected = messageId  });
              }
              child: Container(
                 child: Text('This is a message'),
              ),
               
              ...
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Hope it will help somebody! Have a nice day.