# Can touch gestures be passed to sibling widget(s)?

Tags: flutter, touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: MaterialButton(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Text("DSG"),
          onPressed: () {
            print("Drawer sent gesture");
          },
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Container(
        height: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: MaterialButton(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("DKG"),
            onPressed: () {
              print("Drawer kept gesture");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know that the [IgnorePointer & AbsorbPointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600747/flutter-ignore-touch-events-on-a-widget) widgets can be used to pass gestures from parent to child & vice versa, resp. but what if I want to pass to a sibling widget, e.g., from drawer to body?

Only gestures belonging to the 1st child of 1 sibling should be passed to the other, e.g., I am asking that "DSG" & "DKG" both be clickable once the drawer is opened, i.e., gestures should pass through the drawer scrim.