# How to prevent ripple effect on surrounding InkWell when tapped on InkWell inside

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Let's say that I have this widget:

```dart
Card(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Test'),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I would like to disable (prevent showing) ripple effect on `Card`/`InkWell` only when the `RaisedButton` is tapped, but to show it when the `Card` is tapped (i.e. outside the button). Is there any way to achieve this effect?

I think the generalized question can be: *How to prevent ripple effect on surrounding InkWell when tapped on InkWell inside?* If you take a look at the source code then you can see that `RaisedButton` has `Material` and `InkWell` widgets that cause ripple.

[Here is the full sample code](https://gist.github.com/orestesgaolin/c2326e4f08a428198ffbebf1402d3462).

[image]

Comment: @Eugene I want to show ripple when tapped on the Card itself

Comment: Have you tried [IgnorePointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600747/flutter-ignore-touch-events-on-a-widget)?

Comment: @Tokenyet how would you recommend to use IgnorePointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a quick hack, check it out:

```dart
Container(
  width: 180,
  height: 120,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Card(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Test'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: This works in this situation so solves the problem, but frankly I have a bit more complex widget tree so maybe someone has more robust solution. Either way thanks for the clever hack.

Comment: Dominik Roszkowski have you found a better solution? My widget tree is complex too.

Comment: This solution worked for me without any problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can handle the logic inside `onHighlightChanged` method;

```
Color _color;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(
      child: Card(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: _color,
          highlightColor: _color,
          onTap: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onHighlightChanged: (value) {
                if (value) {
                  setState(() => _color = Colors.white);
                } else {
                  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                    setState(() => _color = null);
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Text('Test'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: overcomplicated and has artifacts at the edges

Comment: @Eugene Haha, it could be but someone already posted using Stack so I used different approach, check out the updated screenshot, problem solved at edges.

Answer (score 2):

try this out https://dartpad.dev/7ff7f5756d93db2d4ed6a4b9a6d75208. I used hack with wrapping in `InkWell` the widget you want to surround with parent `InkWell`