# How can I ignore Mouse Hover events for a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to (conditionally) prevent mouse hover events from affecting a certain widget (tree).

#### [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)

I thought that `IgnorePointer` would be the solution here, based on [how you would prevent touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611970/6509751). However, `IgnorePointer` does not work for mouse hovering.

---

How do I prevent mouse hover events from affecting my widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expanded [`MouseRegion`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) in a `Stack` to absorb all mouse hover events for your widget:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    child, // <---- your widget that ignores mouse hover events.
    const MouseRegion(
      child: SizedBox.expand(),
    ),
  ],
);
```