# how to filter data based on tag in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a screen where need to filter data based on category types and transaction type.

Its working fine but it results null when filter list is empty, I can manage with some logically tricks but it will be lengthy coding..

is there any other better way to filter data properly even if filter tag is empty and
should display all records based on transaction type

like

transactiontype='Expense'
filtertags=[]
result:
it should display all expense transactions

transactiontype='Expense'
filtertags=['Food']

result:
it should display all expense transactions of Food

```
class TransactionModel {
  String category;
  double amount;
  bool isExpense;

  TransactionModel(
      {required this.category, required this.amount, this.isExpense = true});

  String printData() {
    return 'Category:' +
        category +
        ' Amount: ' +
        amount.toString() +
        'isExpense:' +
        isExpense.toString();
  }
}

List<String> _filtertags = ['Food'];// if this list is empty it should show all posible records
String transactiontype = 'Expense';

List<TransactionModel> transactions = [
  TransactionModel(
    category: 'Shopping',
    amount: 4300,
  ),
  TransactionModel(category: 'Food', amount: 2200,isExpense: true),
  TransactionModel(category: 'Loan', amount: 400, isExpense: false),
  TransactionModel(category: 'Food', amount: 300,isExpense: false),
  TransactionModel(category: 'Other', amount: 100,isExpense: true),
];

void main() {
  var resultdata = transactiontype == 'All'
      ? transactions
          .where((element) => _filtertags.contains(element.category))
          .toList()
      : transactiontype == 'Expense'
          ? transactions
              .where((element) =>
                  _filtertags.contains(element.category) &&
                  element.isExpense == true)
              .toList()
          : transactions
              .where((element) =>
                  _filtertags.contains(element.category) &&
                  element.isExpense == false)
              .toList();

  for (var x in resultdata) {
    print(x.printData());
  }
}
```

Comment: yap you can show all, also you can show favorite/most active items

Comment: will add more filters like based on date, transaction mode but getting result null when no filter tag is selected.....want to know better way instead of lengthy codes

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify like

```dart
    var result = [];

    if (transactionType == 'All' || transactionType.isEmpty) {
      result = transactions.toList();
    } else {
      bool isExpense = transactionType == 'Expense'; 
     
      //add more filter when needed and comare with model class
      result = transactions
          .where((element) =>
              _filterTags.contains(element.category) &&
              element.isExpense == isExpense)
          .toList();
    }

    for (var x in result) {
      print(x.toString());
    }
  });
```

Comment: No Sir.. This is not what I am mean to... I mean List<String> _filtertags = []; and transactionType='Expense'. it should show all data of expenses but here it is showing null because filtertags is empty

Comment: my code working properly if my _filtertag is not empty...To solve I added more if but it looks very lengthy coding for these two level data filtering...

Comment: long time i am back to flutter,,,hahahhah...sir can u help to solve this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSdYgI0kw-o

Comment: nice to see u..reached 52k..Congratulation

Comment: Thanks & not so sure about yt link