# How to show a popup dialog with blur background in flutter?

Tags: dialog, flutter

I want to achieve blur background behind dialog on `SimpleDialog` class. What I'm looking for is something similar to this, but for flutter.

[Github Android project](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/Blur-behind-alert-dialog)

**EDIT:**
I already checked this question, but this is about the Dialog, I want to implement it on `SimpleDialog`.

Comment: check the backdropfilter class https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html

Comment: @diegoveloper can you show me  the code on how to implement it on SimpleDialog class please, so that I can accept your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do the "frosted glass" effect in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter)

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot that is not about the dialog, I wanna do it on dialog!

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi I understodd that. You can simply apply the effect to your underlying widgets and open a dialog. Moreover, you can work with overlays.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot thanks for your time, but Dialog itself makes a dark background itself, so blurring all widgets, is pointless IMO, and about overlays, can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Just wrap your `Dialog` inside `BackdropFilter`

```dart
return new BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
    child: Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
      backgroundColor: Color(ColorResources.BLACK_ALPHA_65),
      child: _dialogContent(),
    )
);

Widget _dialogContent() {}//Your dialog view
```

Comment: This for some reason doesn't work on debug builds but works great for release builds.

Comment: @Westy92 I believe this has now been fixed (for anyone looking at this in the future). Using Flutter version 3.7.0 yields no issues.

Answer (score 27):

I implemented blured background with showGeneralDialog method to make a blur transition as smooth as possible. Here is an example:

```
showGeneralDialog(
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierLabel: '',
    barrierColor: Colors.black38,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    pageBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('blured background'),
        content: Text('background should be blured and little bit darker '),
        elevation: 2,
        actions: [
            FlatButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
   ),
   transitionBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2, child) => BackdropFilter(
       filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 4 * anim1.value, sigmaY: 4 * anim1.value),
           child: FadeTransition(
               child: child,
               opacity: anim1,
           ),
       ),
   context: context,
);
```

Comment: Working Perfect!!

Comment: I second that, works great!

Answer (score 8):

In flutter, The dimming effect behind the dialog and bottom sheets is done using a class named **'ModalBarrier'**. So what you can do is just modify the code where it dims the background.

You can easily search the file in **'IntelliJ'** by using the shortcut **'Double shift'**

First, you need to

`import 'dart:ui' show ImageFilter;`

Then in the build method change **(Line: 96)**

```
child: color == null ? null : DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
```

into

```
child: color == null ? null : BackdropFilter(
            filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
            child: Container(color: Color(0x01000000)),
          ),
```

You can change the value of **'sigma'** as per your usecase.

Screenshot : [Blurred Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrY5C.png)

Answer (score 1):

try implementing this code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset('asset url', fit: BoxFit.cover),
      blur(),
    ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}


 Widget blur(){
if(
  //dialog pops up or is active
){
return BackdropFilter(

filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX:5.0,sigmaY:5.0),
);
}

else{
  return Image.asset('asset url', fit: BoxFit.cover);////if dialog not active returns an unfiltered image

  }
 }
```