# How to apply backdrop filter to the entire screen but less a specific widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a cool tutorial dialog box. I want to have a black backdrop filter in the entire screen, but less the popup and the part of the screen that I want to highlight. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the dialog with the BackDropFilter

```
return new BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
    child: Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
      backgroundColor: Color(ColorResources.BLACK_ALPHA_65),
      child: _dialogContent(),
    )
);

Widget _dialogContent() {}//Your dialog view
```

reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825779/blur-background-behind-dialog-flutter)