# Performant blur/opacity in Flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, opacity, blur

I love the blurry frost effect using a BackdropFilter (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter)).

However, because the BackdropFilter has Opacity and because the widget I'm blurring also has Opacity, the performance is horrendous. This is also because I redraw my widgets a few times a second, but that shouldn't be an issue given Flutter can go 60fps?

I turned on [checkerboardOffscreenLayers](https://flutter.io/docs/testing/ui-performance#checking-for-offscreen-layers) and see checkerboards for miles. :O
The checkerboards happen due to `blurScreen`, not due to `widgetToBlur` but `widgetToBlur` does slow down performance probably because (in my real code, not this example) it's calling setState() multiple times a second.

Is there a more performant way to make blurs/opacities? The link above says to apply opacity to widgets individually. I can't do that with the blur though (`blurScreen` below), because the BackdropFilter has to be stacked on top of my widget-that-does-the-redrawing.
I removed the blur effect and my performance is way better (no checkerboards, app doesn't crash).

build() code in question:

```
final widgetToBlur = Container(
  child: Opacity(
    opacity: 0.3,
    // In my actual code, this is a Stateful widget.
    child: Text('Spooky blurry semi-transparent text!'),
  ),
);

final blurScreen = BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.0, sigmaY: 3.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: _backgroundColor.withOpacity(0.3),
    ),
  ),
);

return Container(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      widgetToBlur,
      blurScreen,
      Text('This is in front of the blurred background'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up drawing the widgetToBlur once, blurred, with opacity, using [Paint](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint-class.html) and [Canvas](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html).

This means it only runs the blur and opacity operations once, in `initState()`, and never has to be re-rendered-with-blur throughout the lifecycle of the widget.

If anyone else ends up stuck with this, you can leave a comment and I can help out more.

Comment: Hi Mary, I stuck with this. I'm not sure how should I apply blur using Paint/Canvas. I'd appreciate some tips.

Comment: What are you stuck with? May be worthwhile to post a separate question with a code snippet.

Comment: I tried using `CustomPaint` with a few simple examples. But still I have no idea how to apply blur effect to what it's displayed on the screen with use of Paint/Canvas.

Comment: Does `maskFilter.blur()` change anything?

Comment: I am trying to improve performance in my app and noticed a significant performance hit when having 6 buttons with blur + opacity on. The background changes because it's a gallery. Any chance this would still work if I can reduce the amount of redraws? And do you have any small examples of such way?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem and it also boils down to using canvas and paint.
The only problem now is, if I apply a MaskFilter to the image, not much happens despite the enormously high sigma... Only the edge is a little blurred.

Now the question is why is that so? How did you solved this issue?

```
canvas.drawImageRect(
  image, 
  Offset(0, 0) & srcSize, 
  Offset(-delta, 0) & dstSize, 
  Paint()..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(
    BlurStyle.normal, 100.0
  )
);
```

For those of you who are interested, I have loaded the image in the init function as follows:

```
rootBundle.load("assets/gift_1.png").then((bd) {
  Uint8List lst = new Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
  Ui.instantiateImageCodec(lst).then((codec) {
    codec.getNextFrame().then((frameInfo) {
      image = frameInfo.image;
    });
  });
});
```

P.s. Unfortunately, I can't write any comments yet; therefore here as a contribution, including solution proposal

Comment: My sigma was only 3. When I was playing around with MaskFilter it seemed like I needed to give it more space than the object I'm blurring, and the object needs to be centered. E.g. if your image is 100 x 100, try making your canvas size 200 x 200 and starting your image at (50, 50). This will give the outline of the blur some space. Maybe also try without any offsets, or try just drawing and blurring a solid colored rectangle first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. but I do not know speed.

```
var pr = ui.PictureRecorder();
var canvas = ui.Canvas(pr);

canvas.drawImage(
        img,
        ui.Offset(0, 0),
        ui.Paint()..maskFilter = ui.MaskFilter.blur(
            BlurStyle.normal, 100.0
        )
    );

var pic = pr.endRecording();
return pic.toImage(img.width, img.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to blur an image and it reduces performance you can use **blurHash** by[link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blurhash) package.
I think it can help you also check this link
[blurHash](https://blurha.sh/)