# Flutter : backdropfilter works smooth on simulator but very laggy on real device. what is the optimal solution for blurring background?

Tags: flutter

I need blur behind dialogs and modalsheets, i achieved it but the performance on real device is very bad when the dialogs or modals appear with blur behind them.

I tried different tilemodes and searched on other questions but didn't found anything useful. Is there no efficient way of having blur behind the dialogs and modals?

**EDIT: It is laggy on both debug and release build on real device. Smooth on simulator**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402799/performant-blur-opacity-in-flutter , This might help!