# How to achieve oversaturated effect with flutter

Tags: image-processing, dart, flutter, filtering, fluent-design

I'm creating an flutter widget that adds an acrylic background accodring to the fluent [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic). According to that page there are a few layers other than the blurred image in the acrylic effect, but, given that this could be very expensive I just wish to add the blurred layer and the oversaturated effect according to the last css snippet of [this](https://medium.com/microsoft-design/diy-a-web-version-the-fluent-design-systems-acrylic-material-fe2eac2a40bb) article.

```
backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(125%);
```

I now know that I can add the blur effect using this:

```
BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImaFilter.blur(sigmaX: 30, sigmaY: 30),
  child: child,
)
```

What I need to do now is to add the oversaturated layer.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/43550853/8608146 but not a duplicate