# Adding frosted glass effect over image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a frosted glass effect over an image and based on my research, the below seems to be one way to go about it. However, while there is no linting, it is giving me runtime error: "cannot provide both a color and a decoration". Is there a better way to blur the image in the background with an orange frosted effect?

```
 return Consumer<UserModel>(
  builder: (context, model, _) => Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.75),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/pngguru.com-id-bnwsh.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats mean, if you have a `BoxDecoration` property in your `container`, you need to move `color` to inside `BoxDecoration`

Like that

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.75), // <-------------
      image: DecorationImage(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/pngguru.com-id-bnwsh.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    )
```

Comment: thank you! this works! is there a way i can fade out the image too so that it shows up less?

Comment: Take a look [How do I do the “frosted glass” effect in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter)