# FLUTTER: How make a blurry text?

Tags: flutter, text, widget, blur

I tried to make a blurry text using backdropfilter like this:

`BackdropFilter(
                        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                        child: Text('Hello FLUTTTTER')
                      ),`

I have a problem, the text is not blur but I did like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYRs7Q1vfYI

Comment: this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the video:

> Note that the child won't be affected by the filter, only those widgets
>   beneath it.

So you'd want to use a Stack:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(child: Text('Hello FLUTTTTER')),
    BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
        sigmaX: 5,
        sigmaY: 5,
      ),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: it should be dynamically wrap the text by text size

Answer (score 15):

if you wanna blur the text or the whole container, use the ImageFiltered widget to wrap your widget,

```
ImageFiltered(
    imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
    child: Container(child: Text('your text')),
  )

Container(
child: ImageFiltered(
    imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
    child: Text('your text'),
  ))
```

if you wanna blur the container except it's content, use BackdropFilter to wrap your text widget

```
Container(
   child: BackdropFilter(
    imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
    child: Text('your text'),
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomPaint(
              foregroundPainter: RectBlurPainter(
                   rectWidth: 15,
                   blurSigma: 3.5,
                   ),
              child: Text("my blur text"),
            )
```

My RectBlurPainter is this:

```
class RectBlurPainter extends CustomPainter {
  double rectWidth;
  double blurSigma;
  RectBlurPainter({@required this.rectWidth, this.blurSigma});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   // This is the flutter_screenutil library
   ScreenUtil.init(width: 750.0, height: 1334.0, allowFontScaling: true);

   Paint paint = new Paint()
    ..color = OurColor.green
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.square
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = rectWidth
    ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, blurSigma);
    Offset center = new Offset(0, 6);

   canvas.drawRect(center & Size(180.w, 5), paint);
 }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
   return true;
  }
 }
```