# Blur cards in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to know how I can generate a blur as well as in the image in Flutter

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to card image?

Comment: Yes, the blur that appears on the sides of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the output through the frosted effect.

Refer to this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter).