# Create glass UI with flutter

Tags: flutter, effect, aero-glass

as title say I'd like to create a ui like this but I can't obtain the same result.

[image]

Right now I'm using this code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('images/greydrop.jpeg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
          appBar: AppBar(...),
          body : ....
```

I'm using an image with different type of grey.
My result is the follow :
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do the "frosted glass" effect in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a plain grey image you cannot see the distortion happening I guess.

Try using a colored background like [THIS](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614850523060-8da1d56ae167?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8bGlnaHQlMjBjb2xvdXJ8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80) in the same code.